# How does synthesis of HDL code work?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

**First the context:**
I have a VHDL code (entity/architecture) that deals with some memory inside an FPGA (I cannot modify this piece of code). This memory has two ports. The port A can be used to perform a read operation and the port B can be used for a write operation. (You can see the instantiation of this code later in the post).

My objective is to have a working FIFO interface using the above VHDL code.
Here is the entity of my FIFO:

```
--Packages used
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
library work;
use work.memory_ram.all

--Entity declaration
entity fifo is
    generic (
            g_RST_SYNC  : std_logic := '1';   --synchronicity of the reset, 1=synchronous, 0:asynchronous
            g_RST_POL   : std_logic := '1';   --polarity of the reset, 1=active_in_the_high_state(1), 0=active_in_the_low_state(0)
            g_WIDTH     : natural   := 4608;  --maximal number of columns of pixel across all images
            g_DEPTH     : natural   :=   64   --maximal width of the elements fo the FIFO
            );
    port(
        --control signals
        i_reset   : in  std_logic;  -- reset
        i_clock   : in  std_logic;  -- clock
        --flags
        o_fifo_full         :  out std_logic;   --indicates if the fifo is full
        o_fifo_empty        :  out std_logic;   --indicates if the fifo is empty
        --signals for user, port A used for read operation
        o_data_read_A       :  out std_logic_vector(g_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  --data read on port A
        i_enable_read_A     :  in  std_logic;                             --read enable on port A
        --signals for user, port B used for write operation
        i_data_to_write_B   :  in  std_logic_vector(g_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  --data to write on port B
        i_enable_write_B    :  in  std_logic                              --write enable on port B
        );
```

Here is the architecture of my FIFO:

```
--Body declaration
architecture a1 of fifo is

    signal s_addr_data_A :  std_logic_vector(width(g_WIDTH)-1 downto 0);    --read at this address on port A
    signal s_addr_data_B :  std_logic_vector(width(g_WIDTH)-1 downto 0);    --write at this address on port B

begin


    --INSTANCIATION
    --instanciation of some memory manage by an other vhd file
    inst_memory : entity work.memory_ram(a1)
    generic map(
                WIDTH      => g_WIDTH,   --width of an element of the ram
                DEPTH      => g_DEPTH,   --depth of the ram (number of elements)
                )
    port map(
            -- PORT A (RW), will be used for reading operations
            CLKA        =>  i_clock,                --clock A
            RSTA_N      =>  i_reset,                --reset A
            ADDRA       =>  s_addr_data_A,          --adress A
            DOA         =>  o_data_read_A,          --data output A
            REA         =>  i_enable_read_A,        --read enable A
            -- PORT B (RW), will be used for writing operations
            CLKB        =>  i_clock,                --clock B
            RSTB_N      =>  i_reset,                --reset B
            ADDRB       =>  s_addr_data_B,          --adress B
            DIB         =>  i_data_to_write_B,      --data input B
            WEB         =>  i_enable_write_B,       --write enable B
            );



    --PROCESS
    --update the flags and the indexes
    update_fifo_flags_full_empty : process(i_clock, i_reset)

        variable v_number_elements  :  unsigned(width(g_WIDTH)-1 downto 0);
        variable v_fifo_full        :  std_logic;
        variable v_fifo_empty       :  std_logic;

    begin

        --===============================================================
        --ASYNCHRONOUS RESET
        --===============================================================
        --asynchronous reset if authorized by the generic g_RST_POL and polarity test of the reset by the generic g_RST_SYNC
        if i_reset = g_RST_POL and g_RST_SYNC = '0' then

            --some pice of code to reset variable and some signals

        --===============================================================
        --RISING EDGE ON CLOCK
        --===============================================================
        elsif rising_edge(i_clock) then

            --===========================================================
            --SYNCHRONOUS RESET
            --===========================================================
            --synchronous reset if authorized by the generic g_RST_POL and polarity test of the reset by the generic g_RST_SYNC
            if i_reset = g_RST_POL and g_RST_SYNC = '1' then

                --some piece of code to reset variable and some signals

            --===========================================================
            --PROCESS BODY
            --===========================================================
            else

                --SEQUENTIAL CODE 1
                --update the number of elements in the fifo
                if i_enable_write_B = '0' and i_enable_read_A = '1' and v_fifo_empty = '0' then
                    v_number_elements := v_number_elements - 1;
                elsif i_enable_write_B = '1' and i_enable_read_A = '0' and v_fifo_full = '0' then
                    v_number_elements := v_number_elements + 1;
                end if;

                --SEQUENTIAL CODE 2
                --update the full and empty flags
                if v_number_elements = 0 then
                    v_fifo_full   :=  '0';
                    v_fifo_empty  :=  '1';
                elsif v_number_elements >= g_DEPTH-1 then
                    v_fifo_full   :=  '1';
                    v_fifo_empty  :=  '0';
                else
                    v_fifo_full   :=  '0';
                    v_fifo_empty  :=  '0';
                end if;
                o_fifo_full   <=  v_fifo_full;
                o_fifo_empty  <=  v_fifo_empty;

                --SEQUENTIAL CODE 3
                --we assign the next address to read on
                --if the fifo is not empty, then we increase the index by 1
                if v_fifo_empty = '0' then
                    if unsigned(s_addr_data_A) > 0 then
                        s_addr_data_A  <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(s_addr_data_A) + 1);
                    else
                        s_addr_data_A  <=  std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, s_addr_data_A'length));
                    end if;
                end if;

                --SEQUENTIAL CODE 4
                --we assign the next address to write on
                --if the fifo is not full or if we want to read and write, then we increase the index by 1
                if v_fifo_full = '0' or (i_enable_write_B = '1' and i_enable_read_A = '1') then
                    if unsigned(s_addr_data_B) < g_DEPTH-1 then
                        s_addr_data_B  <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(s_addr_data_B) + 1);
                    else
                        s_addr_data_B  <=  std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, s_addr_data_B'length));
                    end if;
                end if;

             end if;
            --===========================================================
            --END OF THE PROCESS BODY
            --===========================================================

        end if;
    end process;

end a1;
```

**Now my question:**
I know that in VHDL, the code inside a process "consists of the sequential statements whose execution is made in the order defined by the user". 
On the other hand, 2 processes are "concurrent processing".

In my code above, I have indicated 4 parts.

- The first part (named "SEQUENTIAL CODE 1") is updating the number of elements in the FIFO,
- The second part (named "SEQUENTIAL CODE 2") is updating the empty flag and the full flag of the FIFO,
- The third part (named "SEQUENTIAL CODE 3") is updating the index/address for the next read operation
- The fourth part (named "SEQUENTIAL CODE 4") is updating the index/address for the next write operation

The second part "needs" the first part to be performed before starting.

The third and fourth part need the second part to be finished before starting.

However, the fourth part does not need the third part to be performed to be executed and the third part does not need the fourth part to be performed to be executed.

So my question is:

1. Will the synthesizer create some logic that will perform the first part then the second part then the third part then the fourth part (in a single clock period)?

Or

2. Will the synthesizer create some logic that will perform the first part then the second part then the third and fourth part at the same time (in a single clock period)?

(I am using Vivado by the way)

Comment: I read you question not as "how to improve the efficiency..", but more as "How does synthesis of HDL code work". The latter can not be answered in a few lines of text. Also, you have the answer available: run the Vivado synthesis tool and study what comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synthesis tools will figure out the data dependencies and try to produce an "optimal" result based on that. As a result, if there are no data dependencies, the resulting logic will be parallel. The order of statements in the source code only control precedence (last assignment in a block wins).